# About a proof of Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Recently I learned about the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. The theorem is the following:

In $\mathbb R$ every bounded sequence contains a convergent subsequence.

A sequence $a_n$ is bounded if $a_n \in [-C,C]$ for some $C$. The proof that I saw was doing a bisection of $[-C,C]$ into subintervals of decreasing length. I understand the proof but I found another proof that seems slightly less complicated but I don't know if it is correct. Please can someone read my proof and tell me if it is correct?

Proof: If $a_n$ is bounded then $A = \{a_n \mid n \in \mathbb N \}$ is bounded. By the axiom of completeness $a = \sup A$ exists. By the definition of $\sup$ for every $k$ there is $a_{n_k} \in A$ with $|a_{n_k} - a|<{1 \over k}$. The $a_{n_k}$ are a convergent subsequence of $a_n$.

Comment: In addition to what @Did said, the "bisection of intervals" proof is an important and useful proof technique, which I think you should take some time to get used to.

Comment: Also, a set cannot contain repeated elements, where a sequence can, e.g. $a_{n}=1, \forall n$ vs $A=\left \{ 1 \right \}$. So I am not sure how will you extract the sub-sequence from the set you constructed from the original sequence?

Comment: $a_n=1/n$ is bounded, and $\sup\{a_n:n\in\mathbb N\}=1$, but I don't think there is a subsequence converging to $1$.

Comment: I don't think the definition of sup used here is correct. It should be: $a=\sup A \Leftrightarrow \forall \varepsilon >0,\exists x\in A:a-\varepsilon \leq x$ and $y\leq a, \forall y\in A$

Comment: blue's mistake is that the definition of $\sup$ doesn't guarantee the subindices will follow any appropriate order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake was that I assumed there are infinitely many $a_n$ near the $\sup$ of the set. But this is not implied by the definition of $\sup$.

Comment: This is the only pertinent answer to the question.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter The answer by LutzL is helpful to me because it shows why my approach does not work and how to rescue it.

Answer (score 2):

If you take the sequence $(-2,2,-1,1,-1/2,1/2,-1/4,1/4,...)$ your argument using the supremum completely breaks down. However, you can rescue your approach by considering the limes superior, for instance in the form of

$$s=\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n}a_k=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\sup_{k\ge n}a_k.$$

For $\varepsilon_j=2^{-j}>0$ and $N_j\in\mathbb N$ you will find an index $k_j\ge N_j$ with $s-ε<a_{k_j}\le s$. Then find the next index with $N_{j+1}=k_j+1$.

Comment: Where you wrote $N$ should it be $N_j$?

Comment: Yes. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

The completeness of the real line and Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem are actually [equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers) hence invoking the former to prove the latter is questionable.

Comment: How is this questionable?

Comment: @Did Well, we need one of those to be talking about the real numbers. I really don't see how it is questionable.

Comment: @BrianScholl The two results are of comparable complexity and logically equivalent.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff See comment above.

Comment: @Did Yes, but we usually take the axiom of completeness as given or prove it via the construction of the reals, depending on the course. So, completeness is given or proven without mention of Bolzano-Weierstrass, then we use completeness in this proof. I see nothing questionable or circular about that. Another example: Axiom of Choice and Zorn's Lemma are equivalent, so is it questionable to prove Zorn's lemma, even though we accept Choice as true in ZFC?

Comment: @Did Also, how else do we prove equivalence than by using one to prove the other? So, proving equivalence after proving the truth of one of them proves the other.

Comment: @Did I still disagree. The Axiom of Completeness is usually a given truth any student can use. Indeed, it equivalent to BW and NIP, but to be talking about the real line we need to assume either of those hold.

Comment: @BrianScholl The crux of the matter seems to lie in the fact that some curricula (including, probably, the one you were subjected to) present the completeness of the real line as an axiom. This is deeply wrong, and it probably implies that one "forgets" to prove afterwards that the structure called the real line, constructed by the way one prefers, is indeed complete. So, yes, if completeness is "given", one may want to use completeness to prove BW--but completeness should not be "given", except possibly in a first phase.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff See comment above. Addendum: "to be talking about the real line we need to assume either of those hold" Certainly not, both are consequences of a proper definition of the real line, which ought not to involve them.

Comment: I don't think it is "deeply wrong", in particular if that axiom is presented in beginners courses of real calculus for non-mathematicians (which as most courses almost everywhere), @Did . For mathematicians there's usually an added explanation about these matter and whether the sup is presented axiomatically or not students *know* there are other approaches.

Comment: @DonAntonio You seem to confirm my point--except for the somewhat dismissive remark at the end. If you mean that everybody knows anyway which is which, isn't this optimistic view disproved by the whole discussion above?

Comment: No, not everybody @Did, but "mathematics" students are aware, or should be (here we could, perhaps, agree) that there are other approaches. Others don't even need this knowledge to work pretty fine thier way into calculus.

Comment: @Did I also said that when the reals are constructed, completeness is typically one of the first things verified (Baby Rudin is the usual reference for this). So, when completeness is proven in the construction, is it not then usable to prove BW?

Comment: @Did I agree with the fact that the construction of the reals itself provides us with completeness, but from a student's point of view, completness is usually given as an axiom, with the whole "real line" package. I understand your objection, but I don't think it applies here. At any rate, the student can pick any book that construct the reals and proves it is complete, but we're facing the axiomatic rather than the constructive point of view here. Then it is completely natural to use completeness to prove BW, NIP. Of course, it'd be great if students prove they are all equivalent!

Comment: The recent treatment of the number system usually starts at the top by introducing the axioms system of the real numbers, including some kind of completeness, usually order completeness. There is nothing to prove there, the axioms are as they is. All propositions of real analysis can be proven starting from these axioms. -- On the other hand, an axioms system is just a wishlist of properties that one wants a mathematical object to have. There is no guarantee that it does not lead to contradictions or characterizes a unique object. That's why a model is constructed, here the Dedekind cuts.

Comment: @LutzL Sorry but once again completeness of the real line is not an axiom. I am not sure to understand the restrictions in your comment ("recent", "some kind of") but I am quite sure that the end of it is simply rephrasing (after apparently denying it) the objection I made in my second comment to Brian. Please make up your mind... :-)

Comment: @Did I think one can have diffrent views on this issue. There is up to isomorphism only one complete ordered field and that is the real line. That such a complete ordered field exists is something one proves by an explicit construction, but actually using properties of the construction that are not preserved under isomorphisms is weird. I don't want to have to ascribe a truth value to $3\subseteq\pi$.

Comment: Of course it is an axiom of the real field that every bounded set has a supremum. If not for such a completeness axiom, the rationals and the Dedekind cuts of the rationals would both be models of an ordered archimedean field, however, they are obviously non-isomorphic.

Comment: @Did Is it still questionable to use completeness to prove BW when one verifies completeness in the construction of $\mathbb{R}$ without any mention of BW in its proof? That's the main point I was trying to make. It shouldn't be questionable to prove $Q$ from $P$ if the veracity of a $P$ was verified (whether through construction *or by axiom*) separate from any use of $Q$, even if $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent.

Comment: The axiom of completeness is an axiom of the real numbers.

Comment: @blue Obviously, you did not read the discussion above. Perfect.

Comment: Really great discussion on the theory of real numbers. I tend to favor the approach based on construction of real numbers over the axiomatic approach. In my view the axiom of completeness is too much powerful compared to other field and order axioms and hence it makes more sense to show the construction of reals and make it a theorem. For example, why don't we present the set of rationals as the smallest set satisfying field axioms and of characteristic zero? Why do we insist on saying that a rational is a ratio of two integers?

Comment: Continuing with previous comment, I believe that the presenting rationals as ratio of integers makes us connect the rationals with the simpler concept of integers. Similarly it seems much easier to comprehend if we create reals out of rationals thereby showing how complex and beautiful structure of reals emerges from simplicity of rationals. Regarding the current question I believe one should know proof of the equivalence between between various competing completeness results like BW, NIP, Dedekind Theorem use them freely wherever needed.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Yes. The obstinate confusion between an axiom and a theorem is a little unsettling though.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Indeed, the "axiomatic" presentation simply postpones (or even, omits...) the task of checking that the naïve extension we know of the set of ratios of integers *miraculously* fits the bill. (Thoughtful comments, by the way.)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I read your comment carefully. I understand you say that (1) some educational systems present the completeness of R as an axiom but (2) students are free to discover it is not, by personal supplementary readings. Two remarks: Re (1), only some ed.systems do that, not all, and I am sure you will agree that some choices of a given ed.system can be good or disastrous from a mathematical point of view. Re (2), your optimism seems to be refuted by the sincere reactions on this page of users who were exposed to the "axiom" presentation but never reached the second phase you advocate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your argument is that you cannot state that $a_{n_k}$ is a convergent sequence.

(Hint: it may not even be a sequence in $(a_{n})$).

All you know is that for every $k$ there is an element $somewhere$ in the sequence $(a_{n})$ that is in a neighbourhood of size ${1 \over k}$ of $a$.

However your argument can be made correct if you identify the property such elements $a_{n_k}$ must have in order to create a convergent sequence, and show that such a sequence exists.

Hint: When is a bounded sequence necessarily convergent?